# Loopback 4 and EJS Templates

Tags: ejs, loopbackjs, loopback4

We are building an API that needs to send emails to users. We integrated nodemailer into our Loopbck 4 project, and plan to use EJS for email templates.

To my surprise, there does not seem to be any proper documentation available on how to send emails from a loopback controller using EJS templates.

How do we go about generating email body from EJS templates in our loopback controller?

One of the reasons we are confused is because the documentation on Loopback 3, seems to suggest that EJS is pre-configured, which makes us believe that its already there:

https://loopback.io/pages/en/lb4/readmes/loopback-example-relations.html#configure-server-side-views

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any special configuration to use EJS in LB4.

```ts
import ejs = require('ejs');
import nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const template = '<%= people.join(", "); %>';
const data = ['geddy', 'neil', 'alex'];
const html = ejs.render(template, data);

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({...});

const sentMail = await transporter.sendMail({
  to: '...',
  subject: '...',
  html,
});
```

Have a look at [@loopback/rest-explorer](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/packages/rest-explorer/src/rest-explorer.controller.ts), it uses EJS to render the front-end.

Comment: Thank you for that. I did end up doing somewhat like what you mentioned. However, I was  looking at more in line with loopback's architecture of dependency injection, where you would inject templating rather than explicitly calling EJS everywhere you needed it.

So, ended up creating an interface and a service called Templating and injected it. We were looking to see if there was already a "templating" injectable ready made in loopback.